# When do i use subscriber id in send relationship (DE)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

When I create a DE, when do I use "in send relationschip" subcriber id instead of subscriber key?

Comment: when you have subid instead of subkey, most likely never

Comment: ok thank u so much EazyE.